# Restore old / pre-42 Chrome Bookmarks manager

Tags: google-chrome

The new bookmarks manager (`chrome://bookmarks/`) is now set as default in Chrome 42.

Features like copy/paste are missing and I find selecting multiple bookmarks or creating new folder much harder now.

How can I restore the old bookmarks manager ?

Comment: You need to disabling [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/2y8khx/material_design_bookmark_manager_for_chrome/) flag. [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5gw2O.png) of the new flag.

Comment: Was pretty shocked when I saw this just now, and all my folders were gone, all bookmarks moshed together in one big mess. Thanks for the question - and the answers obviously ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Go to URL `chrome://flags`
2. Disable `enable enhanced bookmarks`
3. Relaunch your browser and that's it.

Comment: Direct link to flag: `chrome://flags/#enhanced-bookmarks-experiment` (should be changed from "Default" to "Disabled").

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anymore... Sigh
Here's the link. It worked on a few of my computers, but now there are three that won't change back!
chrome://flags/#disable-new-bookmark-apps

Answer (score 2):

Even lazier:

1. Go to [chrome://flags/#enhanced-bookmarks-experiment](http://chrome://flags/#enhanced-bookmarks-experiment)
2. Set to Disable
3. On the bottom click Relaunch, or simply restart Chrome